# SQL Order rows with each column of a type

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jpa-2.0

My column called type-row has the following values (A, B, C, D, E...) I need to make a query which will order the result sorting by the column type-row but I don't want them all together I want the result to be interpolated as follow

```
id --- some-column -- type-row
1  ---  'bla1' ------- A
2  ---  'bla2' ------- B
3  ---  'bla3' ------- C
4  ---  'bla4' ------- D
5  ---  'bla5' ------- E
6  ---  'bla6' ------- A
7  ---  'bla7' ------- B
8  ---  'bla8' ------- C
9  ---  'bla9' ------- D
```

and so on...
Is there anyway to make this on SQL or even JPA? I'm using Postgresql with JPA

Comment: the sample output shows that you are ordering by `id`. Also how database can know how to order your `type-row` as you have alphabets repeated then how the DB will know which one should come first.

Comment: I'm assuming you want: the first A, the first B, the first C, the first D, the first E, the second A, the second B... etc. Not familiar enough with postgres, but in a subquery or temp table you could order by the type-row, then assign a type-row id based on that ordering, then order by that new value plus type-row.

Comment: @bd33 that's exactly what i want!  Any suggestion how can i achieve that?

Comment: Like I said, I don't know postgres syntax so I can't really help you too much with the code. But to explain it in english: Query the data ordered by the id for each distinct type-row and assign an incrementing id (figuring out which row is the first A, the second A, etc) as typeID, then query the original data set ordering by the new typeID field first, the type-row second. This should show you all the firsts (first a, first b) and the type-row ordering should ensure it is in alpha order.

Comment: I suggest you provide an example that demonstrates your actual problem instead of the current unhelpful one, which indicates you might as well order by `id` or `some-column`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in SQL by enumerating the values for each value of `type-row`, which you can do using window functions:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by typerow order by id),
         typerow;
```